# Are commented methods good practice?

Tags: magento2, methods

When looking inside Magento 2 core code, I found some commented methods, as it was in Magento 1 :

```
 * @method string getState()
 * @method string getStatus()
```

I know how it works technically, and the interest for the developer, but is it a good practice in terms of coding? Does-it add some overhead to magento, or the compilation does the job?

Comment: It isn't good practice, but you don't have to care about it. Of course You shouldn't push code with commented methods if you really don't have to - I am sure that you will not have to :P

Comment: OK thanks you but can you explain me a little bit why it is a bad practice? Because it is lazy work? Or because it is less clear?

Comment: I think it's not a bad practice. It's helpful for IDE hint suggestion, for example PHPStorm.

Answer (score 1):

As you know Magento work with magic php methods. In current Magento installation you can see most of getter and setter as a realized functions, but Magento still use magic methods.

For developers this phpdoc hints is a big plus. You can get all possible methods by IDE, for example like this - [image: magic hints]

Comment: OK so we shoutd see it as a hint mecanism. For instance to see exactly which kind of attribute could be accessed insise an entity?

Comment: Yes, this is just a hint mechanizm to let you know which attributes can be acessable in class.